# How can I Merge two cells vertically in RDLC Report?

Tags: rdlc

How can i merge two cells vertically in RDLC report like B or C in the image?

[image]

Comment: what does this have to do with c#?

Comment: Sorry, not C#, I want it in rdlc report

Comment: in report builder 3.0 i can simply select the 2 cells and right click -> merge cells ... does that work for you?

Comment: thank you, But merge cell only works for horizontal example A cell in the image. But I want to merge vertically like B and C.

Comment: Is cell b already a merged cell ?